# Change iOS Devices Status bar with Animation affects

Tags: ios, swift, reachability

I wanna create an app, that will check the internet Connection, based on the internet connection class if it returns Nil, the statusBar will be Red. And Blue if there is a connection.

But i didn't found any Useful tutorials or an explanations e.g. some other answers says you should use Reachability class, but when i try to use this class an error says " Undeclared type of Reachability Swift".

Another thing i could use Static Images but it will make the app looks Ugly. instead When you share a connection from ur iPhone, the status bar will be changed to blue with some Animation affects "Refer to the pic ". How can i learn to do such a thing ?

[image]

it looks static but actually there is some affects going on.

---

**EDIT**

I found how to change the Status bar color which was pretty Easy.

1: From the object Library Drag a View

2: Put it on the top resize it to take the Length & height of the status Bar

3: Make sure the View is Still Selected click on Pin and check all the Dashed orange lines and make sure they are solid, also in Each box insert 0. also make sure Constrain to Margin is unchecked. then add 4 Constraints

4: then Make an outlet of the View you just created in your Swift Controller Class named let's assume

```
@IBOutlet weak Var changeViewColor: UIView!
```

5: Use Whatever API u feel right for Checking for Internet Let's assume X will take the Boolean value for checking Internet Function.

```
if x == False
{
     changeViewColor.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
else
{
  changeViewColor.backGroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

The status bar is transparent. Create a view, put it behind the status bar and change the color of the view based on the notifications from Reachability.